# syntax error in jquery.min.js (var f=b.call(a,c))

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

All,
I use the jquery.min.js lib to have a rotating image on my website.
In fact it uses 2 JS files:

1. ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js
2. jquery.cycle.all.js

The code looks on my page looks like this:

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#slider1') .cycle({
    fx: 'fade', //'scrollLeft,scrollDown,scrollRight,scrollUp',blindX, blindY, blindZ, cover, curtainX, curtainY, fade, fadeZoom, growX, growY, none, scrollUp,scrollDown,scrollLeft,scrollRight,scrollHorz,scrollVert,shuffle,slideX,slideY,toss,turnUp,turnDown,turnLeft,turnRight,uncover,ipe ,zoom
    speed:  'slow', 
    timeout: 5000 
});
}); 
</script>
```

Running the code throws a syntax error in Jquery.min.js at the following statement "var f=b.call(a,c);" causing my other JavaScript code not to run properly anymore...

I have no idea where to start looking for the problem..
Anyone any idea how to solve this ??

Comment: If you use the un-compressed jQuery version then where is the error thrown? `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js`

Comment: Where is `slider1` defined?

Comment: It is impossible to have a syntax error in that file. Double check that you are looking at the correct file, or try again with empty browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably its a case of conflicts.

Instead of your first js file use this

src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"

Answer (score 0):

You have a space where it shouldn't be:

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#slider1')/* SPACE HERE */.cycle({
        fx: 'fade',
        speed: 'slow',
        timeout: 5000
    });
}); 
</script>
```